# Defect ID corresponding to a TestID in HP Quality Center?

Tags: vb.net, vba, hp-quality-center, defects

I wrote a little tool in VB Script last year to retrieve the TestID with the following code.

```
Dim TSTestFact = tsObject.TSTestFactory
Dim TestSetTestsList = TSTestFact.NewList("")

For Each tsInstance In TestSetTestsList
            Dim tid As String = tsInstance.ID
            Dim testqcID As String = tsInstance.TestID
            Dim testname As String = tsInstance.Name
            Dim statusOfTest As String = tsInstance.Status
Next
```

This is working fine. Now, also Defects are available in QC and I  need to know a "Defect ID" corresponding to a TestID. Any suggestion how to access the "Defect ID" in Quality Center?
Thanks

Comment: Any hints on any other programming language is also fine. Most important is the way to access "Defect ID". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your for loop add following logic

```
Dim tsTest as TSTest = tsInstance
Dim linkFactory as LinkFactory = tsTest.LinkFactory
// From link factory object extract defects which are linked to corresponding test
```

Thanks,
Gaurav